# Why can't change session's expires duration setting in connect-mongo + express.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

app.js

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sample);
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var sessionExpireTime = 10000000; // 10000 sec
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection[0],
  db: config.db.name,
  clear_interval: sessionExpireTime / 1000  // second
});

app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'your secret here',
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + sessionExpireTime)  // millisecond
  }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Welcome!'});
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login', {title: 'login'});
});

app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = {name: 'John'};
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

When call "/login" then redirect to "/" page.
And document created in "sessions" of the MongoDB collection.

But req.session.user is destroyed from req.session after 10 seconds.
It will return to the login screen when you reload the page.

I am aware that interval to monitor clear_interval of connect-mongo is not expired the cookie.
Will there the necessary settings of something in order to change expire duration of req.session.user?

Thank you I received your relationship to unfamiliar my English...

Answer (score 0):

The `maxAge` property should be an absolute number of milliseconds, not a date:

```
cookie: {
  httpOnly: false,
  maxAge  : sessionExpireTime
}
```

There are also some other issues with your code:

```
mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection[0]
```

That should be `mongoose.connections[0]` (or `mongoose.connection`, which is the same).

The `clear_interval` property doesn't seem to exist in (at least the current version of) `connect-mongo`. The way it expires sessions is using MongoDB's `ttl` feature (which runs once per minute).

Comment: Thanks for replied! The maxAge type is number? oh, I was mistaken.
Then connect-mongo make cookie session, maxAge number of seconds from the sessions collection that is generated by the connect-mongo, timing the cookie is deleted is connect-mongo bring clear_interval time. Do I fit in this recognition? By the way, is what's there is a benefit that can be obtained by you other than 1 clear_interval of connect-mongo?

Comment: @AmuroNishizawa I edited my answer because I notices some other problems.